# Vector directed line segment and integral

Tags: integration, vectors, vector-analysis

Let $\overrightarrow{F}$ =$\overrightarrow{i}$ +$\overrightarrow{j}$. How would you place a directed line segment C of length 1 in the xy-plane so that the work integral ∫$_{C}$ $\overrightarrow{F}$ · $\overrightarrow{d}$r is a maximum? a minimum? zero?
What would the maximum and the minimum values of the integral be?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: The work is maximized when parallel to the force, and minimized (0) when perpendicular to the force.